# "Gradle task assembleDebug failed" using VsCode and either ADV or real device

Tags: android-studio, visual-studio-code, android-gradle-plugin, flutter, android-virtual-device

The VsCode's debug mode isn't launching the app any more, eiter through the AVD or a real android device. Used to working perfectly on both until yesterday.

I am getting an error

> Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
>
> Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
>
> Exited (sigterm)

I ran flutter doctor -v

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.0.0, on Microsoft Windows [version 10.0.17134.523], locale fr-FR)
• Flutter version 1.0.0 at F:\flutter_src
• Framework revision 5391447fae (6 weeks ago), 2018-11-29 19:41:26 -0800
• Engine revision 7375a0f414
• Dart version 2.1.0 (build 2.1.0-dev.9.4 f9ebf21297)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 28.0.3)
• Android SDK at F:\Android_sdk
• Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
• Platform android-28, build-tools 28.0.3
• ANDROID_HOME = F:\Android_sdk
• Java binary at: F:\Android_src\jre\bin\java
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1136-b06)
• All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Android Studio (version 3.2)
• Android Studio at F:\Android_src
• Flutter plugin version 31.3.1
• Dart plugin version 181.5656
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1136-b06)

[√] Connected device (1 available)
• Android SDK built for x86 • emulator-5554 • android-x86 • Android 8.1.0 (API 27) (emulator)
```

I have to say that I have absolutely no idea of what went wrong.

I don't think it is code related, has I haven't made huge impacting change to my project. Other than that error inside the debug console, it isn't throwing me anything else.

### Edit

Flutter run -v

```
[ +128 ms] executing: [F:\flutter_src\] git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic @{u}
[ +245 ms] Exit code 0 from: git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic @{u}
[        ] origin/stable
[        ] executing: [F:\flutter_src\] git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
[  +73 ms] Exit code 0 from: git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
[   +2 ms] stable
[        ] executing: [F:\flutter_src\] git ls-remote --get-url origin
[  +88 ms] Exit code 0 from: git ls-remote --get-url origin
[        ] https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
[        ] executing: [F:\flutter_src\] git log -n 1 --pretty=format:%H
[  +99 ms] Exit code 0 from: git log -n 1 --pretty=format:%H
[        ] 5391447fae6209bb21a89e6a5a6583cac1af9b4b
[        ] executing: [F:\flutter_src\] git log -n 1 --pretty=format:%ar
[  +80 ms] Exit code 0 from: git log -n 1 --pretty=format:%ar
[        ] 6 weeks ago
[   +1 ms] executing: [F:\flutter_src\] git describe --match v*.*.* --first-parent --long --tags
[ +253 ms] Exit code 0 from: git describe --match v*.*.* --first-parent --long --tags
[        ] v1.0.0-0-g5391447fa
[ +308 ms] executing: F:\Android_sdk\platform-tools\adb devices -l
[+4275 ms] Exit code 0 from: F:\Android_sdk\platform-tools\adb devices -l
[        ] List of devices attached
[  +19 ms] No connected devices.
[  +20 ms] "flutter run" took 4 413ms.

#0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:26:3)
#1      RunCommand.validateCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/run.dart:249:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      FlutterCommand.verifyThenRunCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:379:11)
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      FlutterCommand.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:335:33)
<asynchronous suspension>
#4      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:142:29)
<asynchronous suspension>
#5      _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1124:13)
#6      _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1021:19)
#7      _runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1516:10)
#8      runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1463:12)
#9      AppContext.run (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:141:18)
<asynchronous suspension>
#10     FlutterCommand.run (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:326:20)
#11     CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:196:27)
<asynchronous suspension>
#12     FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:401:21)
<asynchronous suspension>
#13     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:142:29)
<asynchronous suspension>
#14     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1124:13)
#15     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1021:19)
#16     _runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1516:10)
#17     runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1463:12)
#18     AppContext.run (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:141:18)
<asynchronous suspension>
#19     FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:361:19)
<asynchronous suspension>
#20     CommandRunner.run.<anonymous closure> (package:args/command_runner.dart:111:29)
#21     new Future.sync (dart:async/future.dart:224:31)
#22     CommandRunner.run (package:args/command_runner.dart:111:11)
#23     FlutterCommandRunner.run (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:241:18)
#24     run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:60:20)
<asynchronous suspension>
#25     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:142:29)
<asynchronous suspension>
#26     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1124:13)
#27     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1021:19)
#28     _runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1516:10)
#29     runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1463:12)
#30     AppContext.run (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:141:18)
<asynchronous suspension>
#31     runInContext (package:flutter_tools/src/context_runner.dart:43:24)
<asynchronous suspension>
#32     run (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:51:10)
#33     main (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:51:9)
<asynchronous suspension>
#34     main (file:///E:/b/build/slave/Windows_Flutter_Packaging/build/archive/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/bin/flutter_tools.dart:8:3)
#35     _startIsolate.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate/runtime/libisolate_patch.dart:287:32)
#36     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate/runtime/libisolate_patch.dart:171:12)
```

EDIT 2 : Thanks to Siavash for speaking about "flutter clean".
It solved the problem !

Still curious about the "why" of this problem tho.

Comment: Hi, Could you please try flutter run -v and add the log here? Usually a flutter clean will fix these kinds of issues.

Comment: Ooooh, just ran "flutter clean" and it is working now. Thank a lot !

Answer (score 1):

Thank to Siavash : flutter clean, from inside the project folder,  solved the issue (or simply by using the VSCode terminal).

Answer (score 0):

here I have a answer. See steps below:-
1- Go to your flutter folder where you saved, go and run the 'flutter_console.bat' file. a console will be open.
2- Type "flutter doctor".:-
3- It will show all the problems in your flutter setup. In my case you can see:-

C:\Users\M A Hafeez>flutter doctor

Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):

[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.5, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.685], locale en-US)

flutter_run

[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
X No Java Development Kit (JDK) found; You must have the environment variable JAVA_HOME set and the java binary in your PATH. You can download the JDK from https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/.

[!] Android Studio (not installed)

[√] VS Code (version 1.52.1)

[√] Connected device (1 available)

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.

Basically my error was about Java, that I have no installed before facing this error.

Hope this will be helpful. :)

Enjoy Coding